# Dereference a scalar variable of type class

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to loop through a .csv file, depending on one column value i the go further to see if a file with the same name as the value in the column exists

the code i am using is as follows:

```
<cffile action="read" file="C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/kelly2/debitorders.csv" variable="csvfile">

<cfoutput>
<cfloop index="index" list="#csvfile#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#">

    <cfif FileExists(ExpandPath(listgetAt('#index#',5).txt))>
    xxx
    </cfif>

       #listgetAt('#index#',1)#<br>
       #listgetAt('#index#',2)#<br>
       #listgetAt('#index#',3)#<br>
       #listgetAt('#index#',4)#<br>
       #listgetAt('#index#',5)#<br>
       #listgetAt('#index#',6)#<br>
       #listgetAt('#index#',7)#<br>
       #listgetAt('#index#',8)#<br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

however when i run it i get the following error:

```
You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members.


The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/wwwroot/kelly2/upload.cfm: line 6
4 : <cfloop index="index" list="#csvfile#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#">
5 : 
6 :     <cfif FileExists(ExpandPath(listgetAt('#index#',5).txt))>
7 :     xxx
8 :     </cfif>
```

i have tried putting the cfif tags into a try and catch, according to google this fixed the issue for most people, but it did not work for me

Comment: You should also validate the list length first. Verify it is what you expected before accessing the elements. Also, if you are new to CF, be aware that most list functions ignore empty elements. Consider using arrays instead. You can preserve any empty elements by using [`listToArray`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f0f.html) and using includeEmptyElements=true. Nothing to do with your question, but most of those `#` signs are unnecessary.

Comment: Given the importance of the content you are working with, you should definitely validate ... a lot.

Comment: Hi Leigh! Thanks! Its just a project I am doing for myself so luckily my screw ups won't cause an economic collapse I do however do validation on the data once i get it out of the csv

Comment: Okay, that is reassuring to hear ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 <cfif FileExists(ExpandPath("#listgetAt('#index#',5)#.txt"))>
```

instead of

```
 <cfif FileExists(ExpandPath(listgetAt('#index#',5).txt))>
```